# configuring OpenCV for all projects Visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working with OpenCV on Visual Studio 2010, it works fine, but I'm wondring if it's possible to make a configuration that will be valid for all projects in windows . 
instead of  configuring every project.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is. You need to use **CMake**. Make a folder that contains all the projects of OpenCV in different subfolders. You will need a cmakelists.txt file in the top folder that includes all the subfolders. On each subfolder you will need to have your source codes in  **src** folder and your headers in a **include** folder. CMake will create a VS studio project for all your opencv different projects and will find authomatically the libs and link them.

Now, how to create the cmakelists.txt of each OpenCV project? Something like this:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT( project_name )

FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${PROJECT_NAME} {OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Also check this [links](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FindOpenCV.cmake) to set your cmake opencv projects. It is a pain the first time, but believe me that then is realy easy to create your projects, it is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

To specify a per-user directory list

1.On the View menu, click Property Manager.

2.In Property Manager, click a configuration-and-platform node; for example, Debug | Win32.

The node expands and displays a user property sheet such as Microsoft.Cpp.%platform%user, where %platform% is a system-defined value such as Win32 or X64. The %platform% value and the platform for the project must be the same.

3.
Either double-click the user property sheet, or click the user property sheet and then click Properties in the shortcut menu.

The %user Property Sheet%Property Pages dialog box is displayed, and the VC++ Directories node is highlighted.

4.
Edit the directory lists, as described earlier in step 3 of "To specify a project directory list".

Comment: I already did this but it doesn#t change the fact that I have setup every project

Comment: how you set the enviroment ?